# get_defined_vars Serialize / Deserialize

Tags: php, sql, debugging

Is there a concise way to serialize/ deserialize the output from 'get_defined_vars()'?

I realize there are some fairly large hurdles here, including recursion and system variables, etc but there's got to be a way.

FYI, my goal is to be able to serialize the environment to a database for debugging later (dump the environment with an identifier, come by later pull the serialized environment and code after the identifier (this is what the identifier is for) and run it (exact playback.) Not worried about normalization for the time being (premature optimization and such.)

Any ideas? Is this too deep a rabbit hole for a one man band with a limited timeframe to reasonably pursue? Or am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variables with:

```
$saved_vars = serialize(get_defined_vars());
```

You can restore them with:

```
extract(unserialize($saved_vars));
```